# How to Dynamically Add Calendar Events via JSON using the Ionic Native Calendar Plugin

Tags: javascript, json, ionic-framework, ionic2, calendar

Good day,

I'm currently building an ionic app and making use of the [Ionic Native Calendar plugin](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/calendar/). I want to use this plugin to be able to dynamically change the calendar event parameters associated with it via JSON linked to a Firebase database and not set these in-app as per the demo (as my calendar events will always change). The calendar parameters you can set include, strings and a start and end date, which leads me to believe that this might be possible to achieve?

I currently have the app working fine using the method below, as per the documentation, but this method does not allow me to update the data dynamically as I have to put the calendar parameters in the app, specifically in the `home.ts` file, as per my current situation now...

In my ***`home.html`*** file I have a button that once clicked should create a calendar event:

```
<button ion-button (click)="createEvent()">Add to Calendar</button>
```

In my ***home.ts*** file I have the following function set:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

constructor(...) {

    firebase.database().ref('events').on('value', snapshot => {
      this.events = snapshot.val();
    });

  }
```

Then outside the `constructor` still in my `home.ts` file I have the following function written...

```
createEvent() {
    this.calendar.createEvent('Easter Celebration', 'myChurch', 'Be there or be square', new Date(2017, 9, 20, 13, 0, 0, 0), 
    new Date(2017, 9, 20, 14, 0, 0, 0)).then(() => {
      console.log('Event Created!');
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log('Oops, something went wrong:', err);
    });
  }
```

My current JSON structure (which pulls in other info on my page) currently looks like this:

```
"events" : [ {
    "image" : "http://via.placeholder.com/512x800",
    "title" : "Easter Weekend Celebration",
    "day" : "10 April 2017",
    "photo" : "http://via.placeholder.com/512x512/000",
    "address" : "4 Pybus Rd, Sandton, New York“,
    "times" : "Sundays, From 08h00 - 11h00",
    "info" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod.”,
    "RegisterURL" : "https://www.google.com",
    "calendar" : "some-data"
```

My JSON file is linked to a Firebase database.

The problem is that I cannot dynamically change the calendar values using the method above. I would like to know how I can possibly achieve the same by having the values being called from a JSON file rather than me having to have them in the app as per my example. I already have a JSON file controlling other data dynamically in my app, so I would like to then be able to add the calendar values to this too.

Comment: OK where is the problem? Is there an error? Where is the json?

Comment: @David I've updated the question, sorry. But to answer you, the problem is that I cannot dynamically change the calendar values using the method above. I would like to know how I can possibly achieve the same by having the values being called from a JSON file rather than me having to have them in the app as per my example. I already have a JSON file controlling other data dynamically in my app, so I would like to then be able to add the calendar values to this too.

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure if I understand your question but why don't you use `JSON.parse(yourJsonFile)` and then use the resulting object in your `create()` function?

Comment: @David I don’t know how to? This is what I was hoping to get assisted on. I’m new to Ionic and working with JSON data, and so far my app used JSON data stored in strings and I was able to execute that easily. Now I’ve hit a wall in trying to set up this last step. If you can lead me down the right road / share an example on how I can convert the data to be able to input it in JSON strings that will be great, so I can dynamically load the data. Thanks.

Comment: If you can tell me where _exactly_ the json is stored I can probably put an example together for you. Also an example of how the content of your json file could be useful.

Comment: @David Ok, I've updated my question to answer your questions. Thanks!

Comment: I answered this in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46838993/how-to-convert-new-date-into-json-string/46839043#46839043

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to answer this based on your latest updates, if thats not what you wanted to do let me know an I'll update my answer accordingly:

So you are saying you get your json from firebase, thats not a file.

To always have an up to date version of the json in an instance variable you have to create a construct like this one:

```
export class MyClass {
  public events; // this is where we save your json data so its accessible in the whole class

  constructor(...) { // here you should have injected your firebase lib
    firebase.database().ref('events').on('value', snapshot => {
      this.events = snapshot.val();
      console.log(this.events); // for debugging
    });
  }
}
```

And then you can access it in your `createEvent()` function like that:

```
createEvent() {
  this.calendar
    .createEvent(
      this.events.events[0].title,
      this.events.events[0].address,
      ...
    )
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Event Created!');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Oops, something went wrong:', err);
    });
}
```

Please mind that the `events` is `undefined` until the data is loaded from firebase.

Comment: I've updated my question to illustrate how I have Firebase set-up in my `home.ts` file - and how I'm targeting a specific JSON node on this page, which consists of my event details (as per my JSON example). So I'm not sure if your answer will still be fine for my current setup, please have a look? Thanks.

Comment: Ah you're using the js client of firebase not AngularFire2. I updated my answer accrodingly.

Comment: Ok, thanks! So based on your answer, my JSON will then look something like this for the calendar paremeters based on the `string` inputs: `"events" : [ {
    "title" : "Easter Celebration",
    "address" : "myChurch“,
    ...` ? How about the calendar date and time values, because currently in my `home.ts` file I set them up like this: `new Date(2017, 9, 20, 13, 0, 0, 0)` They are not string values?

Comment: Yes I wrote my answer based on your json example :-) but if you check the `console.log()` you can easily check that. Well that again depends how the date looks in the json response, if it has the correct format you can use it directly to create a new date, if not you will have to split it and build a date object with the parts.

Comment: Hi there! I've been really struggling to try to get this `new Date(2017, 9, 20, 13, 0, 0, 0)` parameter converted and to work as a JOSN string in my app, so I've been unable to fully test your answer - because without the date and time, the app cannot register anything - I've been trying since yesterday. Any assistance here too will be appreciated :)

Comment: If you add the result of this line: `console.log(this.events); // for debugging` to your question I can take a look :-)

Comment: I'm struggling to even get a console.log result in Xcode since I can't run the app with the plugin installed in the browser. I'll keep trying - I'll keep you posted. Thanks!

Comment: You can use safari dev tools to debug the webview of your application when running on device/simulator.

Comment: OK, so I'm getting a Runtime Error undefined is not an object `(evaluating 'this.events.events[0]')`

Comment: Thanks David for all your help. You helped me to get to the solution that I answered in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46838993/how-to-convert-new-date-into-json-string/46839043#46839043